# Is set of vectors dependent in R²

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a set of vectors: {$(-1,2),(2,-4)$}

How can we say that this set of vectors dependent in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

On solving:
$$a(X_1)+b(X_2)=0$$

$a,b=0$, shouldn't it be independent? But answer says that it's dependent.

Comment: The second vector is $-2$ times the first.

Comment: @JohnDouma can you explain how can we find it mathematically?

Comment: Your way will work. You just made a mistake. I am curious. What is non-mathematical about seeing they are dependent by inspection? $2(-1,2) + (2,-4)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The vectors are linearly independent if the *only* possible solution to $aX_1 + bX_2 = 0$ is $ a = b = 0$. Notice that no matter what $X_1$ and $X_2$ are, $a = b = 0$ always gives you a linear combination that sums to zero. That is why choosing scalars that are all zero is referred to as the "trivial" solution to $aX_1 + bX_2 = 0$. If there is a *non-trivial* solution to $aX_1 + bX_2 = 0$, then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are linearly dependent. Notice that in your case $a = -2$ and $b = 1$ are non-trivial choices for $a$ and $b$ that satisfy $aX_1 + bX_2 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment , a simple inspection shows that $X_2=(2,-4)^T=-2(-1,2)^T=-2 X_1$.  But, if you want to show that $aX_1+bX_2=0$ for $a,b$ not null, you have to interpret correctly this equation that is (in components)
$$
a\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\2
\end{pmatrix}+b
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\-4
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
that is equivalent to the linear system
$$
\begin{cases}
-a+2b=0\\
2a-4b=0
\end{cases}
$$

Can you solve it for $a,b$? And show that we have many solutions ?